# Replace all newlines to space except the last

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, tr

How can I replace all newlines with space except the last newline.
I can replace all newline to space using `tr` but how I can do it with some exceptions?

Comment: `sed -z 's/\n/ /g; s/.$//'` - assuming "the last" newline is at the end of the stream (what you probably mean)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use `paste -s -d ' ' file.txt`:

```
$ cat file.txt
one line
another line
third line
fourth line

$ paste -s -d ' ' file.txt 
one line another line third line fourth line
```

Comment: Cool! The `-s` and `-d` options seem like made for this case.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `tr` to replace all newlines to space and pass the output to `sed` and replace the last space back to a newline:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < afile.txt | sed '$s/ $/\n/'
```

Answer (score 8):

Re-implementing [vonbrand's idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114247/26909) in Perl, provided the file is small enough:

```
perl -p00e 's/\n(?!\Z)/ /g' your_file
```

Comment: +1 because this method works for replacements with _multibyte characters_ (as opposed to GNU paste)

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file_with_new_line   | sed 's/\ $//g' > file_with_space
```

Comment: That will remove the last newline as well.

Comment: I don't think so, it is working fine. Have you really tried it???

Comment: Yes I have. Have you? Your `tr` command replaces _all_ newlines with spaces and your `sed` command removes the last space. This results in a file without a final newline and so is not what the question is asking for. By the way, there's no point int using `g` in the `sed` command. Since you're using `$`, it can only match at the end, the `g` is pointless. You also don't need to escape the space, the `\` makes no difference either.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this trick:
`echo $(cat file.txt)`

Comment: Not if there are multiple (adjacent) spaces, or empty or all-space lines, or any word in the file contains shell 'glob' characters/constructs (`* ? [..]`) that match any file(s) in the current directory, or depending on your shell sometimes even if they don't match. Or if the file size exceeds approximately ARG_MAX on shells where `echo` isn't builtin.

Answer (score -2):

Something like `sed -e 's;\n\(.\); \1;'` should do...