# How to run `tr` (translate command) and mute its output?

Tags: bash, text-processing, tr

I'm using `tr` and `sed` command to replace text in my file like this `tr '\n' ' ' < afile.txt | sed '$s/ $/\n/'` and as discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114245/17671). Though running that on a big file will get my console spammed with output replaced text.

So my need is to run the commands, but silence its output.
My google search [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=bash%20run%20replace%20tr%20command%20and%20mute%20its%20output) and calling `tr --help` not helpful to me so I ask here.

Comment: The only purpose of tr is to write transformed content from stdin to stdout. So why silence the output?

Comment: You don't want to mute it, you want to redirect it. Have you noticed that the original file has not changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely that you'd like to discard the output from the pipeline. It is more likely that you'd like to store it somewhere rather than having it flood your terminal.

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' < afile.txt | sed '$s/ $/\n/' >anotherfile.txt
```

This will put the result of the pipeline into the file `anotherfile.txt` rather than onto the terminal.  You are then free to inspect it and to replace the original file with it (`mv anotherfile.txt afile.txt`) if this makes sense with what it is you're trying to achieve.

The `>` at the end of the pipeline is an *output redirection* that will redirect the standard output stream of `sed` into the specified file.  It works in the "opposite way" of the *input redirection* `<` that is used earlier in the pipeline to send the contents of `afile.txt` into the standard input stream of `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can *silence a `command`'s output* by

```
command 1>/dev/null
```

Stuff written to stderr is still displayed.
If you also want to disable output to stderr, use:

```
command 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Even shorter:

```
command &>/dev/null
```

If you want to know more about redirecting file desccriptors, look for `Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error` in the man-page of bash.

Comment: In this specific case, sending the output to the bit bucket means throwing away the result of the operation. You might as well not run the command (`tr` and/or `sed`) at all.

Comment: Why? If I run a compound statement like: `{ tr '\n' ' '| sed 's/\(.*\)/\1\n/' ; } <file 1>/dev/null` I get nothing

Comment: So why did you run it? Where's the result?

Comment: He asked for silencing the output. This accomplishes that, though it is of no use in this special case :)

Comment: Well, in that case, a shorter solution would have been to prefix the whole line with `#`.

Comment: Kusalananda is on point here. Although this answer is technically correct, it probably will not help OP accomplish his REAL task. Maybe it is worth to elaborate more on input/output redirection or to point OP to some useful link. :)

Comment: @FloHe Yes you did. It's a comment.

Comment: Oh, you mean commenting.

Comment: The second example is wrong, I will fix it for you. it says direct fd2 to where fd1 is currently going (no change), then direct fd1 to /dev/null.